# Why am I asked to agree to Xcode/iOS license to compile with a different compiler?

Tags: xcode, gcc

I'm trying to compile some code with a version of gcc which (if I remember correctly) I install with the `port` command of MacPorts.  I am explicitly invoking the compiler by path, and all goes well.  However, as soon as I add the `-g` option, suddenly my compile fails and I get this bizarre error message!

```
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
```

My command line looks like this:

```
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.9 -g -o test test.c
```

What is going on here, and how do I make this error go away? I can compile my code, but I can't compile with debugging which means I can't debug it!

Answer (score 0):

When you're debugging code, you're essentially controlling that process. In a world where even sharing the same chunk of memory is a serious security threat, you obviously need suitable permissions to attach to a process.

Darwin kernel (under your mac's hood) requires gcc to have certain permission. You have to code sign your copy of gcc. Follow [this guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html) and see if it works.